# Rough estimates for training time of deep belief networks

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, deep-belief-networks

I'm still learning about deep learning. However I'm currently interested to know if deep learning architectures scale well or not. Suppose I have a dataset with 1 million training examples, can you give me some rough estimates how much time would it take to train a deep architecture on such a dataset? I know there are lot of hyper-parameters that affect the training time (#layers...etc), but I just want some rough mean estimates since I'm still at the beginning and not aware of all parameters and so on.

I just want to know how well they scale to large datasets.